# How to enable hide button on my typo3 custom ext?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I did an extension that allows you to create custom records (ideas), but this ideas should have the "hidder" field in 1 by default so a back-end user can approve it before displaying it on the front-end.
I have, the "hider" column is there, my model has a hide property which I can set in 1 and the record does not get displayed correctly on the front-end but I don't know how to show the "hide record" button on the back-end.
I need to display the same hide button that categories but in my custom record "ideas" like.
[image]

I don't know much about typo3 so I don't know where this is configured. This is my tx file.

```
<?php
return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:my_custom_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:hk_ideas_idea',
        'label' => 'title',
        'iconfile' => 'EXT:my_custom_ext/Resources/Public/Icons/Extension.svg',
        'enablecolumns' => [ 
            'disabled' => 'hidden',
            'starttime' => 'starttime',
            'endtime' => 'endtime',
        ],
    ],
    'columns' => [ ...(noting about hide field here)... ],
    'types' => [
        '0' => ['showitem' => 'title, description, category, status, user, voted_users'],
    ],
];
```

And this is my tt_content file

```
<?php

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'Vendor.Extension',
    'Ideas',
    'The Ideas Data Record List',
    'EXT:my_custom_ext/Resources/Public/Icons/Extension.svg'
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add enable fields to your `showitem`

```php
'types' => [
        '0' => ['showitem' => 'title, description, category, status, user, voted_users, hidden, starttime, endtime'],
    ],
```

in `columns` section also there will be these configs:

```php
'hidden' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.visible',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'check',
        'renderType' => 'checkboxToggle',
        'items' => [
            [
                0 => '',
                1 => '',
                'invertStateDisplay' => true
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
'starttime' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.starttime',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'input',
        'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
        'eval' => 'datetime,int',
        'default' => 0,
        'behaviour' => [
            'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true
        ]
    ],
],
'endtime' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.endtime',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'input',
        'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
        'eval' => 'datetime,int',
        'default' => 0,
        'range' => [
            'upper' => mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2038)
        ],
        'behaviour' => [
            'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true
        ]
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Still not showing up. Probably there is something else.

Comment: Did you clear the caches after all. ALL caches? @arderoma

Comment: Yes I did @biesior

Comment: also in tca fileare there config sections for these files?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? No those are all the configs I have.

Comment: Oooh, ok, that's necessary.

Comment: Awesome man thanks! I couldn't find any code like that anywhere.
I have been learning typo3 with a try and error method, the documentation is not helping me much.

Comment: For future: it can be found in any TCA that uses these fields, on the other hand Extension Builder also should generate in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to accepted answer, when learning TCA, it might be helpful:

- TCA is cached, so it is necessary to flush cache when making changes (or configure development system to not cache these files)
- Look at existing configuration in the backend (in Configuration => $GLOBALS['TCA'])

[image: Look at TCA in Configuration module]

- Though it may seem daunting, the TCA reference is actually pretty much up-to-date and in good shape: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ (switch to your version when reading)
- Unfortunately, there is no really good beginner's tutorial for this, except maybe https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html
- The "styleguide" extension is an extension functioning as TYPO3 backend styleguide. It includes a number of TCA configuration examples you can look at and explanatory text. Also, the examples in the TCA reference are often taken from the styleguide. Important: Make sure to generate the sample records. See [How to install and use the "styleguide"](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Examples/StyleGuide.html#).

[image: Open styleguide]

[image: Look at generated records]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this in 'ctrl' add a property

```
'enablecolumns' => [
        'disabled' => 'disabled',
    ],
```

and add an additional column

```
 'disabled' => [
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.enabled',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'check',
            'renderType' => 'checkboxToggle',
            'items' => [
                [
                    0 => '',
                    1 => '',
                    'invertStateDisplay' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

This should solve the problem